# HDF5 read time is highly variable

Tags: c++, hdf5, ram

I am writing a program that reads in many relatively small sized 2d matrices in order to compute various combinations of matrix products. For the sake of this question, the matrices are dense, complex and of shape (80x80). I have roughly 200k of these matrices that need to be read in that are sorted by integer keys like i/j/k/e/.

I have noticed that when I read in from a recently written hdf5 file, the read times are about 6ms. However, if there is a delay the read time (a few mins onwards) is more like 500ms to 2s. This leads me to think that this performance issue is related to whether or not the hdf5 file is in ram or not.

What I am trying to figure out is methods to speed up read time. I am much less concerned about write time. I have also tried to implement parallel read only access, but I think the file is thread locked because individual/parallel processes always print out in lock step with each other. Is it possible to force a file back into ram? This seems like it

I am currently not using compression or chunking, since compression slows read time and chunking doesn't seem necessary for this small of a matrix.

The program is written entirely in c++ using the highfive/h5easy package. This was selected initially for its easy integration with the eigen3 library, however I am not married to it if a better hdf5 package is available.

The hdf5 file is on the order of a few GB (1-10GB) depending on the project.

To pose a concise question, how can I maintain the initial hdf5 read efficiency I am experiencing over longer periods of time when the file no longer persists in ram.

Comment: _"compression slows read time"_ Did you measure this?  It's not unusual for compression to significantly improve disk read time.

Comment: Unfortunately, std doesn't include memory-mapped files. You can use **BOOST**  for portable code, or your OS's memory-mapped file API. This is the fastest possible file read mechanism; it basically uses the virtual memory implementation of your platform.

Comment: how much data are you reading? what's the speed of your disk? are you using compiler optimisations?

Comment: Are you on linux? If so, try to prefetch the file with [`posix_fadvise(…,  POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) This will only help if your read-requests do not overtake the async prefetch read, so start it as early as possible

Comment: If you want parallelization, you have to use multiple processes since the library is single-threaded. For writing you need MPI, for reading you can just fork multiple processes

Comment: I have not tested the assumption that compression will slow down my read times. This an an assumption based on the fact that decompression is an extra step.

Comment: @Homer512, I presently have the code running in parallel with mpi. My understanding of the highfive library is that it supports parallel read/write. My experience is that it is just a thread safe read/write since I don't seem to be able to access the same file by different processes simultaneously.

Comment: @Homer512, does posix_fadvise(...) load the entire file into ram? I have never used/heard of this feature.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, In total I am accessing something like 1-10GB of data 100kB at a time (80x80 complex double matrix). I am unsure of the disk speed. The computation is being done on an HPC cluster. The project is being compiled with -O3.

Comment: Before you go any further you need to measure exactly what you have. Do a disk benchmark, work out the exact speed your code is achieving, if they're close then you're getting the best you can, if they're not then you could at least know the magnitude of the performance you're missing

Comment: You should have mentioned that you run on an HPC cluster from the start! That means it's a network filesystem which brings entirely different performance characteristics with it. In particular, latency is much more important. Reading individual 80x80 matrices is fine on a local filesystem. On a network filesystem you have to read at least a few MiB at once. Read more at once, then manually split it into smaller matrices

Comment: Re `posix_fadvise`: I've linked to the man-page didn't I? It explains that this call starts an asynchronous read operation with the intent of putting the data into the page cache. That may or may not work on a network filesystem

Comment: @Homer512. I think this is likely the issue. I compiled the same code on my desktop with ssd and it is orders of magnitude faster. While I understand your proposed solution, it would require a large rewrite of the program to accommodate the change in the data structure. For the HPC version, I decided to just load the entire file at once and save it in a struct. This takes a hit for parallelization since memory usage is up, but is much faster than reading individual datasets from hdf5 on network filesystem. No changes were necessary on desktop.